# How to align divs in rows html css

Tags: html, css

I have so many `div`s in my website and I want to align them like this with CSS and HTML:

[image]

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin: 16px;">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Music Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the CSS code of all the classes.

Comment: Have a look at "CSS grid" (e.g. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a `Masonry Layout`. Try the Below Code and make necessary modifications.
This snippet uses `CSS-Grids`. You will need to change basic styles on some grid-items to make it look exactly as yours :)

```css
/* CSS reset */
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* Typography --------------------------------------------*/

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.body-text {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.footer-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}



/* Grids --------------------------------------------*/

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 150px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

/* Grid images --------------------------------------------*/

.img {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* Grid items --------------------------------------------*/

.item-4 {
  grid-row: 2/5;
}

.item-5 {
  grid-row: 2/6;
}

.item-6 {
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.item-7 {
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.item-8 {
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.item-9 {
  grid-row: 6/11;
}

.item-10 {
  grid-row: 6/7;
}

.item-11 {
  grid-row: 6/9;
}

.item-12 {
  grid-row: 7/12;
}

.item-13 {
  grid-row: 9/13;
}

.item-14 {
  grid-row: 11/13;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <main class="container">
    <div class="item-1">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/301" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/302" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-4">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-5">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/800" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-6">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-7">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/304" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-8">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/401" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-9">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/900" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-10">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/305" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-11">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-12">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/901" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-13">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/700" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-14">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/402" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-15">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/306" alt="">
    </div>

  </main>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use grid layout

```
.grid-container {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
 }
```

add this to a div and children of the div can be adjusted the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the card divs using `display:flex` property. Give `display:flex` property to your div container and `flex-wrap:wrap` so that the divs can wrap itself. Use any other flexbox properties you like on container after that. So your code might look like this.

```
<div class="card-container" style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin: 16px;">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried I've fixed it, let me know if it is good for you:
This is also responsive..

```
    <style>
      .grid-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 10px;
        
      }
      .card {
        margin: 5px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        flex: 1 1 150px; /* Stretching */
      }
      img{
        width: 300px
      }
    </style>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">

    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" >
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
          Music Name
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
    
</body>
```